# how to fetch columns and take the count from pandas pivot table in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say there is Pandas pivot table

```
country     AFG AHO ALG ANZ ARG     
edition
1800        2    1  1    1   1
1881        3    3  1    3   nan
1882        4    2  4    4   nan
1883        1    1  5    5   nan
1884        3    4  6    1   1
1885        4    5  7    2   3
1886        5   nan 1    2   5
1887       nan  nan 3    6   1
```

After creating a pivot table from a df I am trying to find how many countries have won at least one medal in each edition.

can anyone tell me how to fetch the count of the country from pivot table? in this case the answer should be 2  (ALG,ANZ)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
s = df_pivot.ge(1).all().sum()
# s = 2
```

To get the country names, you can do

```
s = df_pivot.ge(1).all()
s.index[s]
# output: Index(['ALG', 'ANZ'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: why `ge()` ? i was thinking `.notna().all()` with `.loc[]`

Comment: I think the idea is to catch not only `NaN` values but also `0`

Comment: `notna` certainly works since the pivot is the count. I just translated the `at least 1` literally.